# Get facebook page reviews automatically

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to get my page reviews and insert them in the database. The problem is that i need to get this into a cron job. So to access /{page-id}/ratings i need to follow this steps:

1. Need to log in with Facebook in order to get the user session
2. After that, if the user is the admin of the page i can access /me/accounts and get the page token
3. After i take the page token i can get the reviews/ratings by accessing /{page-id}/ratings

I must do all of this automatically. How can i get the user session to use it every time without logging in again.

Comment: Did you get the reviews? I have same problem. I wanted to access the reviews from Facebook pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an Extended Page Token that is valid forever.

If you don´t know how to generated Extended Tokens, here are some articles:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/

Basically, you just need to generate an Extended User Token and call `/me/accounts` with that one to get an Extended Page Token.